# Save position of selected item in RecyclerView after update [Xamarin.Android]

Tags: android, image, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I am making app where i'm using `recyclerView` to handle with images. I must update list of images often (3 sec) but after update - scroll is going to top.
To update `recyclerView` i use this code:

```
adapter = new ImageAdapter(this, DrawableList);
RunOnUiThread(() => recyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter));
```

Is there any way to save position of scroll in `RecyclerView` or updating in background?

Comment: In Java we have a method to get current scrollX and scrollY as `recyclerView.getScrollX()` and `recyclerView.getScrollY()` if you save those values, you can use `recyclerView.scrollTo(x,y)` to scroll to old position.

Comment: Doesn't working :C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I must update list of images often (3 sec) but after update - scroll is going to top.

I think it is possible you just want to keep your `RecyclerView` to be scrolled to the end when you update your images, then you can simply code like this:

```
adapter = new ImageAdapter(imageAlbum);
recyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);
recyclerView.ScrollToPosition(adapter.ItemCount - 1);
```

If you want to scroll to the specific position when you update your images, there is no present Api for now, not like the standard Android API, `ScrollToPositionWithOffset` is a virtual method in Xamarin.Android, we can only scroll to the specific item in the adapter using `RecyclerView.ScrollToPosition` or `LinearLayoutManager.ScrollToPosition`. Also there is no present API for getting the first visible item in Xamarin.Android, we need to create our `LinearLayoutManager` which inherit from `LinearLayoutManager` class and override such methods we may need to use, for example:

```
public class MyLinearLayoutManager : LinearLayoutManager
{
    public MyLinearLayoutManager(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public override int FindFirstVisibleItemPosition()
    {
        return base.FindFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    }

    public override void ScrollToPositionWithOffset(int position, int offset)
    {
        base.ScrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset);
    }
}
```

Now we can scroll to the specific position like standard Android:

```
scrollListener = new MyOnScrollListener();
...

var item = rvManager.FindFirstVisibleItemPosition();
adapter = new ImageAdapter(imageAlbum);
rv.SetAdapter(adapter);
//offset value 200 is fake, you can calculate by yourself
rvManager.ScrollToPositionWithOffset(item, 200);
```